# Sending and receiving xml data over tcp error {"An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"}

Tags: xml, sockets, c#-4.0, tcp

Can anyone please help me. I am trying to send data (just a string initially) over tcp using the code below. This is just an initial test to see that I can write to a port using TcpClient and then immediately read the sent data. The code worked and I could send a string, and read it.

However, all of a sudden it stopped working with the following error:
{"An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"}
Error Code 10054

It looks to me like I have not closed an existing connection or I have exceeded a maximum number of allowed connections.

Using netstat I can only see one tcp port that is listening on my ip address. This is the port I have been using, and as I said above it worked and then all of a sudden stopped working and instead produced the above error.

My knowledge of sending and receiving data this way is very limited.

Can anyone help me find a solution? To either fix the above code or port so I can read the sent string again. Or if anyone has any other code suggestions for sending and receiving xml over tcp? That would be much appreciated.

Many thanks.

```
String response = String.Empty;
TcpClient client = new TcpClient(hostname, port); 

stream = client.GetStream();
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
writer.AutoFlush = false;
writer.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message).Length);
writer.Write(message);
writer.Flush();

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
response = reader.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine(response);

stream.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine. In my working projects I used almost the same code. I propose you to check the following:

1. check the size of block of xml which you send?
2. try if possible to restart tcp server (if you have access to it)?
3. Do you have access to source code of tcp server or maybe you can deploy it to your local developer machine and check its functionality at your local machine?